# Known problems on various Android devices?

Tags: android, device

Is there a site that collects the various issues that exist in various Android devices that an Android developer should know about? Such as "There is a problem with the vibrate feature on phone X. A workaround would be ...".

If not, it would be great if someone sets this up, and allow us developers to add known problems that we experience with our applications on various Android devices.

Comment: It would even be a great sub-section here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have seen somewhere such a site... i'll post it in case I can find it again ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its nice to have such a bug list. 
A simple Google code project with only an issue tracker would be sufficient to track the known issues.

If you find sometime then you can start one and share the link with all so that we can add known issues.

Answer (score 2):

[AndroidFragmentation.com](http://www.androidfragmentation.com/) was created last year, but I haven't heard anything about it since.

Looking at it just now, they have several hundred device specs on hand, submitted by users of [their app](http://code.google.com/p/android-analyzer/), but I didn't notice from a quick look any meaningful way to examine or analyse trends for particular devices.